# How to control DC motor via Arduino and Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, arduino, visual-studio-2017, arduino-uno

I have the following situation. I try to control a DC motor via arduino IDE and window application made in Visual C++ 2017. I'm using a serial port to process the data from Visual Studio into Arduino. Here's the things I want to achieve:

1. I'm using mouse_down event (when I click the button with a mouse, something happens), but it sends just one sign (U, D, R, L) during a pressing, causing a DC motor to move just a little bit. How do I make it run and send the char untill the button is released? Should I use some kind of a loop?
2. I try to control it the same way, using a num keys on keyboard. The thing is, keys are not functional, untill the focus is put on them (they are pressed by/hovered by mouse). Is there a way to get rid of focus?

Thank you for your help.

[Control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12WTt.jpg)

Code snippet for
[arduino code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHZCw.jpg)

```
    data=Serial.read();
    analogWrite(motorPin1,motorSpeed);
    analogWrite(motorPin2,motorSpeed);

    xValues=analogRead(xPin);
    if((xValues>xIdleHigh) or (data=='R')) {
      motorSpeed=map(xValues,xIdleHigh,xRight,motorSpeedLow,motorSpeedHigh);
      analogWrite(motorPin1,motorSpeed);
      analogWrite(motorPin2,motorSpeedLow);
      Serial.print("TURNING RIGHT...");
      Serial.print("\n");
      delay(50);
    } 

    xValues=analogRead(xPin);
    if((xValues<xIdleLow) or (data=='L')) {
      motorSpeed=map(xValues,xIdleLow,xLeft,motorSpeedLow,motorSpeedHigh);
      analogWrite(motorPin1,motorSpeedLow);
      analogWrite(motorPin2,motorSpeed);
      Serial.print("TURNING LEFT...");
      Serial.print("\n");
      delay(50);
    }

    yValues=analogRead(yPin);
    if((yValues<=yUp) or (data=='U')) {
      if(pos<150) {
        pos+=1;
      }
      Serial.print("BARREL UP");
      Serial.print("\n");
      delay(50);
    } else if((yValues>=yDown) or (data=='D')) {
      if(pos>30) {
        pos-=1; 
      }
      Serial.print("BARREL DOWN");
      Serial.print("\n");
      delay(50);
    }
    servo.write(pos);
    delay(50);`
```

Code snippet for 
[visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/punsh.jpg)

```
    private: System::Void button1_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
        if (e->KeyCode == Keys::NumPad6) {
            serialPort1->Open();
            serialPort1->Write("R");
            serialPort1->Close();
        }
    }
    private: System::Void button1_KeyUp(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
        if (e->KeyCode == Keys::NumPad6) {
            serialPort1->Open();
            serialPort1->Write("X");
            serialPort1->Close();
        }
    }
    private: System::Void button1_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
        serialPort1->Open();
        serialPort1->Write("R");
        serialPort1->Close();
    }
    private: System::Void button1_MouseUp(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
        serialPort1->Open();
        serialPort1->Write("X");
        serialPort1->Close();
    }
    private: System::Void button2_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
        if (e->KeyCode == Keys::NumPad4) {
            serialPort1->Open();
            serialPort1->Write("L");
            serialPort1->Close();
        }
    }
    private: System::Void button2_KeyUp(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
        if (e->KeyCode == Keys::NumPad4) {
            serialPort1->Open();
            serialPort1->Write("X");
            serialPort1->Close();
        }
    }
    private: System::Void button2_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
        serialPort1->Open();
        serialPort1->Write("L");
        serialPort1->Close();
    }
    private: System::Void button2_MouseUp(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
        serialPort1->Open();
        serialPort1->Write("X");
        serialPort1->Close();
    }
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    private: System::Void button3_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
        serialPort1->Open();
        serialPort1->Write("U");
        serialPort1->Close();
    }
    private: System::Void button4_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
        serialPort1->Open();
        serialPort1->Write("D");
        serialPort1->Close();
    }`
```

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text within your question, not as image.

Comment: @Max.F For your first question, you can write your code in the loop or time interrupt routine of the arduino system to control the DC motor. For your second question, you can associate key press events with your buttons. You can refer to the following [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/33f765d0-b46b-4a79-b42a-6883d783bc29/c-associate-a-key-with-a-button?forum=winforms), although it is a c # Examples, but the concept is quite simillar.

Comment: What does this have to do with Android?